# Sort a file based on the middle part

Tags: shell-script, filenames, sort

I have below files in unix, I want to sort the files based on date & time in the file names

```
ABC_XYZ.20170201.223147.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170201.223146.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170127.223141.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170125.223139.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170214.223134.txt
```

I am expecting below as output

```
ABC_XYZ.20170125.223139.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170127.223141.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170201.223146.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170201.223147.txt
ABC_XYZ.20170214.223134.txt
```

I tried using `sort -k` and `sort -n`, maybe I am not using them in the right way.

Comment: `sort` alone works on that sample. `sort -t . -k 2` to sort on the part of the line after the first `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the files in the current folder have the same format as described, you could use the following:

```
ls | sort -t . -k 2
```

The `-t` switch sets the delimiter as a `.`
The `-k` switch indicates which key to use for the sort.

With the filename format you have supplied, you don't need the `-n` switch as the number of digits is the same within each filename.  If this is not always the case, you can easily add the `-n` switch, too:

```
ls | sort -n -t . -k 2
```

Again, if there are varying lengths of digits for each section of the filenames, you may want to specify both keys and how far to extend them:

```
ls | sort -n -t . -k 2,2 -k 3,3
```

Comment: Great, that's awesome!